# .NET corrigir URL enviada num POST Request

Tags: .net, asp.net

Boa tarde Amigos!

Estou com um problema ao receber uma Url com o método POST.

Eu faço uma requisição ajax conforme abaixo:

```js
$('#ajaxButton').on('click', function () {
            const data = document.referrer.toString();
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "/negociar-valores.aspx",
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log("deu bom:" + data);
                    window.location.href = "/negociar-valores.aspx";
                },  
                error: (data) => {
                    console.log("deu ruim:" + data);
                }
            });
           
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajaxButton">NEGOCIAR VALORES</div>
```

A constante "data" com o método document.referrer.toString() tem o seguinte valor: "*http://localhost:46729/cotacao-resultados/?destino=194&periodo=17-08-2019%2C22-08-2019&idade=20&idade=&idade=&idade=&idade=*"

Porém na página negociar-valores.aspx, quando solicito o valor da url:

```
NameValueCollection coll;
coll=Request.Form;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(coll.ToString());
```

Invés de receber a url da forma como descrevi acima, recebo desta forma:

"*http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a46729%2fcotacao-resultados%2f%3fdestino=194&periodo=17-08-2019%2c22-08-2019&idade=20&idade=&idade=&idade=&idade=*"

Minha dúvida é a seguinte; existe alguma maneira de converter esse valor recebido para a url correta? substituindo esses "%3a" por ":" e "%2f" por "/" para que eu possa utilizar este dado?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Minha dúvida é a seguinte; existe alguma maneira de converter esse valor recebido para a url correta? substituindo esses "%3a" por ":" e "%2f" por "/" para que eu possa utilizar este dado?

Sim! Use a função `UnescapeDataString` da classe `Uri`:

```cs
string url = @"http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a46729%2fcotacao-resultados%2f%3fdestino=194&periodo=17-08-2019%2c22-08-2019&idade=20&idade=&idade=&idade=&idade=";

Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString(url));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! funcionou!